# Cross Entropy function implemented with Ground Truth probability vs Ground Truth on-hot coded vector

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

Hi I came across a documentation in Pytorch which implement cross-entropy loss function in two ways:

```
# Example of target with class indices
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.empty(3, dtype=torch.long).random_(5)
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()

# Example of target with class probabilities
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.randn(3, 5).softmax(dim=1)
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()
```

One method uses the probability vector of the target, and the other uses it as a one-hot vector. To me, the implementation with class probabilities is closer to the definition of the loss function, but in most places, I have seen the other method. Can someone clarify the difference between these methods?

Thanks

Comment: Since a one-hot vector is a probability distribution, there really is no conceptual difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things worth explaining. From what I understood, you are asking for the following:

- the difference between soft and hard labels.
- As well as the difference between the one-hot and dense encoding of hard labels.

Just to be clear a probability distribution determines how probabilities are distributed over the values of the random variable (here they correspond to the different classes for your classification task). A **soft label** represents the distribution itself, while a **hard label** represents the value of the random variable that has the highest probability (*i.e.* the most probable class).

If you're applying the loss function against a target that represents a probability distribution, its values are positive and sum to one, then this would most likely correspond to a pseudo-label. In practice, this means you are applying a *soft cross-entropy* loss and supervising the whole distribution explicitly.

Now, hards labels are what you can expect to have when using ground-truth annotations. You can choose to represent a label in one of two ways (what is called the encoding of the label):

- either with a one-hot encoding vector, all `0`s, and a single `1` for the *true class*
- or a dense representation which is the index of the *true class*.

With hard labels, only the probability of true class (the class corresponding to the ground-truth information) is explicitly supervised: you are pushing to maximize the probability mass it gets predicted with. Implicitly minimizing the mass of all other labels... since the mass is finite (*i.e.* equal to `1`).

In PyTorch, the utility provided by [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) expects **dense** labels for the target vector. Tensorflow's implementation on the other hand allows you to provide targets as one-hot encoding. This let's you apply the function not only with one-hot-encodings (as intended for classical classification tasks), but also soft target...